# Delphi 7 VCL package Runtime Error 216 when recompiled

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, vcl, recompile

I am still use Delphi 7 :)

I changed (added several properties) to `vcl70` package code and then recompiled it. I created `vcl70.bpl` file, copied it to the Windows System32 folder, and get an error message:

> Runtime Error 216 bla bla..

I copied the original `vcl70.bpl` file to the System32 folder and don't get the error message.

What may be the problem?

Example Code:

```
TForm = class(TCustomForm)
...
published 
  property Test: String read FTest write FTest;
```

Comment: You can't modify Borland's packages like that, and you certainly can't make `interface` changes like that. What are you really trying to accomplish? You will have to find another way.

Comment: On top of expressly being forbidden to recompile Emba packages, consider the risk of putting them in the system directory. What if another program loads this package?